# Dedicate Tomcat threads to servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

Is there anyway to configure tomcat to reserve threads to a specific servlet or webservice?
I understand this could probably be done programatically in a servlet filter.

So suppose I go with the default configuration of 250 serving threads, but I want 20 of them to be reserved for a specific servlet/webservice?

Maybe this is obviously impossible -  if so could someone please explain why?

Im using tomcat 6.

Comment: why do you want to do this ? Tomcat handles threading just fine

Comment: What is the sense of doing so?

Comment: Yea, agreed it may be a weird usecase. I have a specific synchronous service that locks up a lot of the serving threads. Potentially strangling the entire app. Addmittedly by poor design, that will be refactored soon. So I was just curious to see If I could limit the number of threads for that sync. service so that does not happen, and thus sovling my problem in the short time.

Comment: Unless you split your webapp in multiple parts, I don't think you can do this. If you do have multiple webapps, you can also configure some [Executors](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html) to share the pools between several of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
Thinking about it, I dont think is such a strange use case after all.
There is no reference about this in the tomcat docs though, so my guess is that it is not possible.

Comment: It seems like an easier solution might just be to deploy the synchronous service that is eating up threads to a second Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible per the servlet specification. However in Tomcat you can define several connectors running on different ports. Each connector has a separate thread pool:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="10443" />
```

You'll find examples of how to configure thread pools in `server.xml` file undere `/conf` directory in Tomcat.

Now you can access your web applications using both 8080 (default) and 8081 (configured above). Requests through 8081 will use a different thread pool. All you have to do now is route all servlets through 8080 and your specific thread through 8081 (using completely independent thread pool).

If you don't want someone to abuse this, add a servlet filter to check whether correct port is used based on requested URI.

---

However reading your rationale:

> I have a specific synchronous service that locks up a lot of the serving threads

You'll better start and manage your own pool of threads (check out [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) and use asynchronous servlet. Much simpler and portable.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for helping out!
I guess this would be the configuration approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score -6):

why do you want to do this ?

Tomcat handles threading fine, if you reach your max, you would need to increase the max anyway. So what would be the benefit of reserving some ? Reserving some just means you reach the max quicker and don't efficiently use them when not required.

In short don't do this.

Comment: Isolating (almost "sandboxing") web services is not a bad idea in itself. See [this Netflix blog post](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/02/fault-tolerance-in-high-volume.html) for example.

Comment: I guess I cant do it. But why is it such a bad idea to limit the maximum number of serving threads for a service that tends to generate extreme load on the server, while all other services dont - could you please explain why NimChimpsky?

Comment: @fante you are just moving the bottle neck around. Don't see the point myself. Fix the code that you said needs refactoring instead.

Comment: @NimChimpsky So true, and it will be done, but the refactoring will take some time, and was just hoping for a "quick fix", then I got interested in the use case itself.
Thanks for helping out though!

Comment: This *answer* belongs in comments to question since all you are doing is seeking clarification. I found this post because I have the same motivation.  My web service has two types of clients: There are thousands of type A (other background services) and a handful of type B, generally driven by user UI.  I'd like to reserve some threads so that servlets dedicated to type B continue to respond during bursts or heavy load from type A clients, which can easily max out any reasonable thread pool limit that I would set for those servlets.

Comment: if two app deployed on same tomcat insatnce and request for one app consumes all available threads then it hampers the performance of other app.in such scenario thread pool reserve concept required.